# How to Pitch Bend MIDI notes with Java Sequencer

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi

I am trying to apply pitch bend to a MIDI file in Java. The MIDI file consists of two C4 notes and I would like to pitch bend the second note to an interval less than a semitone. I have read the Oracle documentation but I don't really understand how to link all the code together correctly to achieve this. I have this code so far but it is not doing any pitch bend. Can anyone help me achieve the pitch bend, thanks.

```
    final String MEDIA_URL = "../SharpFlat.mid";

    Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    sequencer.open();
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(MEDIA_URL)));

    ShortMessage myMsg = new ShortMessage();
    myMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.PITCH_BEND, 1, 2, 100);
    MidiEvent pitchBend = new MidiEvent(myMsg, 1);

    Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(is);
    Track track = sequence.createTrack();
    track.add(pitchBend);

    sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
    sequencer.start();
```

Also, I don't really understand the arguments in `myMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.PITCH_BEND, 1, 2, 100);`. How do I know what channel to use as the second argument, and what exactly are the third and fourth arguments?

Comment: Pitch bend messages are explained in the [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification).

Comment: I ended up just using a jMusic instrument and setting the exact frequencies of the notes I wanted